# ContentType not set in Mockito test

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

I am trying to get a unit test to work with Mockito and Spring MVC on a RESTful GET controller.  Here is my test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/test-context.xml","/dataaccess-context.xml"})
public class FormControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
FormImplBean formBean;

@Mock
private FormService formServiceMock;

@InjectMocks
private FormController formController;

@Before
public void setup() {
    // Process mock annotations
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    // Setup Spring test in standalone mode
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(formController).build();
}

@Test
public void testGet() throws Exception {
    when(formServiceMock.getFormImplById(1)).thenReturn(formBean);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/Form/form/{id}", 1))
     .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
     .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    verify(formServiceMock, times(1)).getFormImplById(1);
    verifyZeroInteractions(formServiceMock);
}
}
```

And here is my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form/{formId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public FormImplBean getForm(@PathVariable("formId") int formId ) {
    return formService.getFormImplById(formId);
}
```

I keep getting:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set
```

Of course when I go an look at the real controller on the server, using firefox developer tools, I see that the content type is set correctly.

I tried adding the produces="application/json"  to the controller but that did not work,  (nor do I think I should have to right?)

Without the content type check, the test passes fine.
I am using:

Spring 4.2.7 - 
Mockito 1.10.19 - 
Jackson 2.7.0 - 
Junit 4.12

in a maven build

Any Ideas?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you don't need `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` because you're already calling `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`.

Comment: Which annotation did you use for the controller: `@Controller` or `@RestController`?